# batch curl request w/ https address txt file

Tags: configuration, curl, api, set, phone

I have multiple phones I am trying to obtain the up time for phones. I have enabled REST API for all phones and am looking to run CURL scripts to get the value of uptime. I have a script to get the value off of a Polycom phone. The below command works but I have over 3000 devices I would like to do this with. When I run a script of 100 commands I get the output but it is all jumbled together. I have a txt and excel file with all of the IP Adresses of the phones, the username and passwords are the same for all 3000 devices. I am looking for a way to run all commands and then get a text file with the IPADDRESS and return result of the request( IPADRESS:"Status": "2000"" or something similar). I mostly want an easy way to see the results of each curl line per IP address.

***Command***

```
curl -d "{\"data\": [\"UpTimeSinceLastReboot\"]}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@IPADDRESS/api/v1/mgmt/config/get
```

***Output***

```
{“Status”: “2000”, “data”: {"UpTimeSinceLastReboot": "<DAYS_HOURS_MINUTES_SECONDS>"}
```

I was able to add >> /tmp/filename.txt to output a txt file with all of the responses but there was no way to accurately coorilate that to the phone's IP address..

Comment: you haven't given much specific detail about what you are trying to do, so i can only give a very generic suggestion: you already know the ip address, so print it with echo or printf or something before running curl.  or store the output of the curl command in a variable and print them together.   or redirect all output to a file with the ip address as its name.  or....thousands of other variations.

Answer (score 1):

In all examples I assume the file is one IP per line.

**1. curl and magic**

You can achieve Your goal with [`curl(1)`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) and some magic around

```bsh
curl -d "{\"data\": [\"UpTimeSinceLastReboot\"]}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -k \
  -u USERNAME:PASSWORD \
  -w ",%{remote_ip}\t" \
  <(sed 's#^#https://#;s#$#/api/v1/mgmt/config/get#' /path/to/file) \
  | tr -ds '\n\t' '\t\n'
```

I split the command into multiple lines for better understanding:

- I moved credentials from URL to curl parameter
- The key is input from subshell to prefix the ip with protocol *https://* and append the path */api/v1/mgmt/config/get*
- -w option writes **remote_ip** after the response. The format is `,REMOTE_IP<TAB>` used later in tr to create desired format
- piping this through [`tr(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) removes possible newline at the end of response and creates newline at the end (this is not nice but it should work).

Note: In this example the result is

```
RESPONSE,IP
…
```

**2. for loop**

```bsh
for ip in $(cat /path/to/file)
do
  echo -ne "$ip\t"
  curl -d "{\"data\": [\"UpTimeSinceLastReboot\"]}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@$ip/api/v1/mgmt/config/get
done
```

result:

```
IP,RESPONSE
…
```

**3. while loop**

while loop

```bsh
while read ip
do
  echo -ne "$ip\t"
  curl -d "{\"data\": [\"UpTimeSinceLastReboot\"]}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@$ip/api/v1/mgmt/config/get
done < /path/to/file
```

result:

```
IP,RESPONSE
…
```

Comment: thank you Jakub Jindra for your detailed reply. I am getting the following error:

`curl: (3) <url> malformed`

I am going to do some research first to see if I can resolve it.

Comment: Yeah, that may be my fault. What of suggested solutions triggred the error? Can you provide output of curl with additional flag -v ?

Comment: This was the output:

`* <url> malformed
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) <url> malformed`

Comment: doesn't ring a bell to me. can you try `set -x` and calling it. so we can see what exact shell command is executed?

Comment: For sure: 

`* Rebuilt URL to: set/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Could not resolve proxy: -d
* Closing connection 0
curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: -d
curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 10
* <url> malformed
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) <url> malformed`

Comment: no. I meant
`set -x`
and than 
`curl …`

Comment: `Could not resolve proxy: -d curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 10 `

but according to this it seems the problem is argument of -d. There's -d inside doublequotes. Try changing doublequotes to single quotes and remove escapes of the inside doublequotes like this `-d '{"data": ["UpTimeSinceLastReboot"]}'`

Comment: Hi Jakub, I was finally able to get it to do what i wanted. Created a .sh file that looks for a txt file with IPs and return with "IPAddress"+"Status"

'#!/bin/bash

`while read line; do echo result=$(curl -d "{\"data\": [\"UpTimeSinceLastReboot\"]}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k https://Polycom:PASSWORD@$line/api/v1/mgmt/config/get); echo $line+$result=; done < IPsgetUptimeSinceLastReboot.txt `